# What is the difference between myfunc() and return myfunc()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this code, can be jQuery (as it is here) or plain javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#someid").keyup(function(){
    func1();
    func2();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#someid").keyup(function(){
    return func1();
    return func2();
    });
});
```

In the first case both of the functions will be called, but in the second one only the first function is called. Why is that?

Comment: `return` ends the function execution.

Comment: Because that's what [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) does.  It ends the function and "returns" a value.

Comment: In the case of an event handler, returning `false` will stop the default action and stop the event from propagating/bubbling.

Comment: and here's me thinking "return" was one of the more descriptively named keywords

Comment: OK. I answered. But I feel like this question should be closed somehow...

Comment: @dystroy: I agree... but which option to choose... must be a dupe somewhere

Comment: I don't know either, that's why I choose the "no rep answer" option for now...

Comment: @dystroy I *honestly* don't think there's a duplicate, community wiki seems good to me (that's what I do most of the time). Apparently they don't like closing questions like these nowadays :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` ends the function execution.

[From ECMAScript](http://es5.github.io/#x12.9) :

> A return statement causes a function to cease execution and return a value to the caller